# no factory exists problem with Gazebo ros control tutorial

Tags: ros, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

My ros distribution is indigo and my ubuntu distribution is 14.04.

I'm currently learning ros control. And it speed learning curve really makes me frustrated.

Here is my question, I tried the Gazebo ros control tutorial at http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control.

When typing "roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch" it worked at the first time. But things get weird when I come back several days later( Accurately yesterday..... ). I got errors when loading the control_plugin.

[ERROR] [1466858294.522754886, 17.133000000]: Could not load class effort_controllers/JointPositionController: MultiLibraryClassLoader: Could not create object of class type effort_controllers::JointPositionController as no factory exists for it. Make sure that the library exists and was explicitly loaded through MultiLibraryClassLoader::loadLibrary()
[ERROR] [1466858294.522799828, 17.133000000]: Could not load controller 'joint1_position_controller' because controller type 'effort_controllers/JointPositionController' does not exist.
[ERROR] [1466858294.522831954, 17.133000000]: Use 'rosservice call controller_manager/list_controller_types' to get the available types

But when I call the service as the third error suggested I find the effort_controllers/JointPositionController exist.
And when I type "rospack find effort_controllers" I can find the package under ros/indigo/share/
Furthermore at file effort_controller_plugins.xml it actually contain:

name="effort_controllers/JointPositionController" type="effort_controllers::JointPositionController" base_class_type="controller_interface::ControllerBase">

The JointPositionController tracks position commands. It expects a
EffortJointInterface type of hardware
interface.

I try to remove and re-install the effort_controllers use "apt-get" several times but the errors still exist.

Please help me out of this.

Thanks in advance.
Erli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238042/no-factory-exists-problem-with-gazebo-ros-control-tutorial/) by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2016-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I solved this problem just several minutes ago. It turns out the error appears because the .so file is collapsed. So I download the source code from git and re-generate the .so file use catkin_make. The last step would be copy the .so file to /ros//lib folder, and problem solved. And then PROMBLEM SOLVED!

---

Originally posted by [cangjiaxuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/21440/cangjiaxuan/) with karma: 20 on 2016-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0